# PHP post Mysql result to url with Ajax live search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need a little bit of advice on the last stage of implementing PHP and MySQL with ajax live search.

I have got the live search to work perfectly and it shows the results just the way I want them. I have even got it to work by passing the search value via URL and searching on page load.

The issue I am having is when it prints the results it not printing the name of the column only the values for example:

```
<table data-role="table" id="customer" data-mode="reflow" class="border_radius">
    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Post Code</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td id="" class="151">151</td>
        <td id="" class="Brain">Brain</td>
        <td id="" class="Apartado 81">Apartado 81</td>
        <td id="" class="2584">2584</td>
        <td>
            <a href="cart/?tele=" class="btn btn-success btn-lg text-center" id="order_link" '="">Order</a></td></tbody>
                                    </table>
```

The problem with this is i want to post the values to the url for the next page but not sure how to achieve this. I have tried to post the column names but it post all the column name for every id like so:

```
<table data-role="table" id="customer" data-mode="reflow" class="border_radius">
    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Post Code</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td id="AUTO_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE" class="151">151</td>
        <td id="AUTO_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE" class="Brain">Brain</td>
        <td id="AUTO_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE" class="Apartado 81">Apartado 81</td>
        <td id="AUTO_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE" class="2584">2584</td>
        <td>
            <a href="cart/?tele=" class="btn btn-success btn-lg text-center" id="download_link" '="">Order</a></td></tbody>
                                    </table>
```

My PHP code looks like this :

```
namespace AjaxLiveSearch\core;

file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'DB.php') ? require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'DB.php') : die('There is no such a file: DB.php');
file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Config.php') ? require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Config.php') : die('There is no such a file: Config.php');



if (count(get_included_files()) === 1) {
    exit("Direct access not permitted.");
}

if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}

/**
 * Class Handler
 */
class Handler
{
    /**
     * returns a 32 bits token and resets the old token if exists
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getToken()
    {
        // create a form token to protect against CSRF
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        return $_SESSION['ls_session']['token'] = $token;
    }

    /**
     * receives a posted variable and checks it against the same one in the session
     *
     * @param $session_parameter
     * @param $session_value
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function verifySessionValue($session_parameter, $session_value)
    {
        $white_list = array('token', 'anti_bot');

        if (in_array($session_parameter, $white_list) &&
            $_SESSION['ls_session'][$session_parameter] === $session_value
        ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * checks required fields, max length for search input and numbers for pagination
     *
     * @param $input_array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function validateInput($input_array)
    {
        $error = array();

        foreach ($input_array as $k => $v) {
            if (!isset($v) || (trim($v) == "" && $v != "0") || $v == null) {
                array_push($error, $k);
            } elseif ($k === 'ls_current_page' || $k === 'ls_items_per_page') {
                if ((int)$v < 0) {
                    array_push($error, $k);
                }
            } elseif ($k === 'ls_query' && strlen($v) > Config::getConfig('maxInputLength')) {
                array_push($error, $k);
            }
        }

        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * forms the response object including
     * status (success or failed)
     * message
     * result (html result)
     *
     * @param        $status
     * @param        $message
     * @param string $result
     */
    public static function formResponse($status, $message, $result = '')
    {
        $css_class = ($status === 'failed') ? 'error' : 'success';

        $message = "<tr><td class='{$css_class}'>{$message}</td></tr>";

        echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'message' => $message, 'result' => $result));
    }

    /**
     * @param     $query
     * @param int $current_page
     * @param int $items_per_page
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getResult($query, $current_page = 1, $items_per_page = 0)
    {
        // get connection
        $db = DB::getConnection();

        $dbInfo = Config::getConfig('db');

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(AUTO_ID) FROM {$dbInfo['table']}";

        // append where clause if search column is set in the config
        $whereClause = '';
        if (!empty($dbInfo['searchColumn'])) {
            $whereClause .= " WHERE {$dbInfo['searchColumn']} LIKE :query";
            $sql .= $whereClause;
        }

        // get the number of total result
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        if (!empty($whereClause)) {
            $search_query = $query . '%';
            $stmt->bindParam(':query', $search_query, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $number_of_result = (int)$stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

        // initialize variables
        $HTML = '';
        $number_of_pages = 1;

        if (!empty($number_of_result) && $number_of_result !== 0) {
            if (!empty($dbInfo['filterResult'])) {
                $fromColumn = implode(',', $dbInfo['filterResult']);
            } else {
                $fromColumn = '*';
            }

            $baseSQL = "SELECT {$fromColumn} FROM {$dbInfo['table']}";

            if (!empty($whereClause)) {
                $baseSQL .= "{$whereClause} ORDER BY {$dbInfo['searchColumn']}";
            }

            if ($items_per_page === 0) {
                // show all
                $stmt = $db->prepare($baseSQL);

                if (!empty($whereClause)) {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':query', $search_query, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }

            } else {
                /*
                 * pagination
                 *
                 * calculate total pages
                 */
                if ($number_of_result < $items_per_page) {
                    $number_of_pages = 1;
                } elseif ($number_of_result > $items_per_page) {
                    $number_of_pages = floor($number_of_result / $items_per_page) + 1;
                } else {
                    $number_of_pages = $number_of_result / $items_per_page;
                }

                /*
                 * pagination
                 *
                 * calculate start
                 */
                $start = ($current_page > 0) ? ($current_page - 1) * $items_per_page : 0;

                $stmt = $db->prepare(
                    "{$baseSQL} LIMIT {$start}, {$items_per_page}"
                );

                if (!empty($whereClause)) {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':query', $search_query, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
            }

            // run the query and get the result
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             // generate HTML
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                    foreach ($result as $column) {
                        foreach ($dbInfo['filterResult'] as $colid) { //Trying to get the ID of each column
                        $HTML .= "<td id='{$colid}' class='{$column}'>{$column}</td>"; // Table column names just paste as one i.e AUTO_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE
                    }
                }
                $tele = $_GET['tele'];
                {
                    $HTML .= "<td><a href='cart/?tele={$tele}' class='btn btn-success btn-lg text-center' id='download_link''>Order</a></td>";
                    $HTML .= '</tr>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            // To prevent XSS prevention convert user input to HTML entities
            $query = htmlentities($query, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            // there is no result - return an appropriate message.
            $HTML .= "<tr><td colspan='5'>There are no customer with telephone number\"{$query}\" <a href='#customerimport' class='btn btn-success btn-lg text-center' id='download_link'>ADD</a></td></tr>";
        }

        // form the return
        return array(
            'html' => $HTML,
            'number_of_results' => (int)$number_of_result,
            'total_pages' => $number_of_pages
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getJavascriptAntiBot()
    {
        return $_SESSION['ls_session']['anti_bot'] = Config::getConfig('antiBot');
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the timestamp difference between the time page is loaded
     * and the time searching is started for the first time in seconds
     *
     * @param $page_loaded_at
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function verifyBotSearched($page_loaded_at)
    {
        // if searching starts less than start time offset it seems it's a Bot
        return (time() - $page_loaded_at < Config::getConfig('searchStartTimeOffset')) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

My Config.php looks like this

```
namespace AjaxLiveSearch\core;

if (count(get_included_files()) === 1) {
    exit("Direct access not permitted.");
}

/**
 * Class Config
 */
class Config
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $configs = array(
        // ***** Database ***** //
        'db' => array(
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'user',
            'username' => 'name',
            'pass' => '*******',
            'table' => 'table',
            // specify the name of search column
            'searchColumn' => 'TELEPHONE_NO',
            // filter the result by entering table column names
            // to get all the columns, remove filterResult or make it an empty array
            'filterResult' => array(
                'AUTO_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE'
            )
        ),
        // ***** Form ***** //
        // This must be the same as form_anti_bot in script.min.js or script.js
        'antiBot' => "Ehsan's guard",
        // Assigning more than 3 seconds is not recommended
        'searchStartTimeOffset' => 0,
        // ***** Search Input ***** /
        'maxInputLength' => 20
    );

    /**
     * @param $key
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public static function getConfig($key)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, static::$configs)) {
            throw new \Exception("Key: {$key} does not exist in the configs");
        }

        return static::$configs[$key];
    }
}
```

and my HTML look like this

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="search" method="post" action="../cart/index.php" id="ls_form" name="ls_form">
    <?php // Set javascript anti bot value in the session Handler::getJavascriptAntiBot(); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="ls_anti_bot" id="ls_anti_bot" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ls_token" id="ls_token" value="<?php echo Handler::getToken(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="ls_page_loaded_at" id="ls_page_loaded_at" value="<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="ls_current_page" id="ls_current_page" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="ls_query" id="ls_query" placeholder="Type to start search (e.g., 02071234567)" autocomplete="off" value='<?php echo $tele; ?>' maxlength="<?php echo Config::getConfig('maxInputLength'); ?>">
    <!-- Result -->
    <div id="ls_result_div">
        <div id="ls_result_main">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.post({
                        url: "/include/banner-home.php?tele=1234",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            tableId: customer
                        },
                        success: function(data) {}
                    })
                });
            </script>
            <table data-role="table" id="customer" data-mode="reflow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>Post Code</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- Pagination -->
        <div id="ls_result_footer">
            <div class="col page_limit">
                <select id="ls_items_per_page" name="ls_items_per_page">
                    <option value="5" selected>5</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="0">All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col navigation"> <i class="icon-left-circle arrow" id="ls_previous_page"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="col navigation pagination">
                <label id="ls_current_page_lbl">1</label>/
                <label id="ls_last_page_lbl"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col navigation"> <i class="icon-right-circle arrow" id="ls_next_page"></i>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If someone can please advise where I am going wrong or point me in the right direction and would be more than grateful.

Thanks